# Sitecore: patching other include files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, config

Sitecore has a mechanism for patching include files (http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) but I'd like to patch something in the Analytics config, which itself uses this mechanism already.

Rather than add my line to the Analytics include file, it seems cleaner to leave it in my own tiny config; but it doesn't seem to get applied (my breakpoint isn't being hit).

I'm wondering if there's a way to control the order include files are processed in Sitecore, or if this just plain doesn't work?

Comment: Not entirely sure if it would work - which one would be applied first? If your include gets patched first, then the Analytics.config, wouldn't that one possibly override your styles? Can you try changing the Analytics.config with your changes, then check to see if it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible and it does work - You just have to keep in mind the following:

1. You can't **add** new elements to other elements **added** with another patch. Example: In patch A you add a new `<database />` element and in patch B you want to add a new child to the new `<database />` element. Updating attributes works!
2. When you need to patch a patch, the naming of the file is important. Example: You can patch *Analytics.config* by creating a new config file called *AnalyticsPatch.config* which will then be included in the final web.config  section right after the original  Analytics.config.

This is tested and used in production with Sitecore versions 6.4.1 till 6.6.0 Update-4.

Happy patching :)

Comment: point 1 is no longer true: in Sitecore 6.6 I added a new processor to the "startTracking" pipeline which the Analytics config creates. And just to clarify point 2, Sitecore processes include files in alphabetical order - thanks for the idea of appending something to the config.

Comment: If you are adding config files to a project,  use a naming convention that starts with a letter greater than 'S'. This makes it MUCH easier to override any "Sitecore" config files that are already in the include folder. E.g.  Your project is called Contoso. Don't use Contoso for the Config Prefix, use "Radius" or something greater than 'S'

Comment: @Dann or divide your config files over a few folders that define in which alphabetical order you want them processed, so for the files within the folder doesn't matter in what order they get applied and you can name them whatever you want :) but to each person it's own preferred structure ofc...

Answer (score 5):

You can check if your modification to the config file is applied by taking a look at the live-config:

```
www.yoursite.com/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx
```

Comment: There is a cool and very useful utility I found on bitbucket which allows you to see the showconfig file without having to run it in sitecore via the showconfig path. Very useful when working on your build process. http://bit.ly/16PdsNV . Ensure you use the normalise checkbox to create a valid XML version.

Comment: @mikejames FYI, that's a broken link.... 
Anyway, I'm currently changing some contentsearch indexes config and in the showconfig.aspx I notice how it instantly updates all configuration-tags, but somehow the locations-tags remain outdated. I'm wondering whether it's possible to ask sitecore to rebuild everything. Do you guys know any process or tool to rebuild the config file? Thanks!

Comment: @T_D Hi yeah this was awhile ago sorry I've since left the sitecore world of things.

Answer (score 3):

Just for info, and keeping ppl up to date:

It seems that, atleast for newer Sitecore(testet with Sitecore 7.0), it takes subfolders into the calculations. This means that all files in the root folder, /app_config/include is processed first.

Next it takes the config files from the subfolders, i.e. /app_config/include/myfolder, the stuff in myfolder will overwrite what has been configured in the root include folder.

Comment: The point beeing that naming of folders doesnt matter.

I.e. if you make a folder called Include/Afolder, content in AFolder will always overroule nomather file names in that folder

Comment: I've just checked the Sitecore.Kernel.dll from Sitecore v. 6.0.1, and this processing of subfolders is also working with this version of sitecore. I think the approach of subfolders instead of relying on naming, is better.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation where my custom include file was being applied before another include file, which caused unintended issues.  I found that renaming my own config file to something like `zz.MySettings.config` did the trick.

Comment: Yep - Sitecore processes them in alphabetical order.